# How to transform CDATA format from one xml to another?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have  this type of  CDATA  inside xml  tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Data>
<RawData Format="Text"><![CDATA[
<organizationNameEng>fgfgfg</organizationNameEng>
<organizationNameGeo>dfdfdf</organizationNameGeo>
<organizationIdentifier>123456789</organizationIdentifier>
<cardNumber>dfdfdf</cardNumber>
]]></RawData>
</Data>
```

and  i want to  paste this data   (in CDATA  format  and    got xml  like  this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DataPrep xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Lcid="String">
<Job Name="CompleteJob" Type="Normal" Priority="1">
<Cards>
<Card>
<RawData Format="Text"><![CDATA[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<organizationName>fgfgfg</organizationNameEng>
<organizationIdentifier>123456789</organizationIdentifier>
<cardNumber>dfdfdf</cardNumber>
]]></RawData>
</Data>
</Card>
</Cards>
</Job>
</DataPrep>
```

i have  xslt  like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Cards/Card">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="document('content.xml')">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but  as  a  result  i  got  CDATA  formated as  &gt &lt  format what  should  i change  to make desirable result?

Comment: CDATA means that what is up to ]] is raw text _including_ tags and not XML.  You will see this if you do an identity XSLT step.  Did you generate content.xml yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cdata-section-elements="RawData"` on `xsl:output` to designate the elements to be serialized as CDATA section

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="RawData"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Cards/Card">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('content.xml')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```